# Saving a Word Doc directly to Finder

Tags: mac, finder

When I try to "Save as…" a Word document, I used to get a Finder window and could then save it where I wish.  Instead, I now get a short list of possible places to save it.  What happened to the Finder dialog box?

Comment: It would be nice, and easier to answer, if you provided some background information, like - What Mac OS version are you using, Which application you were using (many appications can save as... Word document) What Mac you were using? In any way, the "Save Dialog box" is NOT related to the Finder, and never was (even in Mac OS 1.0 classic). In recent days, it is called "Navigation Services dialog". Still - I think Steve Chambers's answer is correct.

Answer (score 18):

So the Save... dialog box is not as tall as it used to be?

Apple hides the directory structure by default when you first go to save a document and points you to the ~/Documents directory.

To get the listing back click on the downward pointing arrow to the immediate right of the "Save..." or "Save As..." filename. That will expand the dialog box to show the directory structure and allow you to navigate to where you want to go.

Downward pointing arrow location:

[image: save as disclosure arrow]